# What's the purpose of the fixture file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
one:
  title: MyString
  description: MyText
  image_url: MyString
  price: 9.99

two:
  title: MyString
  description: MyText
  image_url: MyString
  price: 9.99
```

Scaffold generator created an YML file that contain above line of codes.
My general understanding is that a test fixture is simply a specification of the initial contents of a model under test. If I can validate within the model like this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, :description, :image_url, presence: true
  validates :title, length: {minimum: 10}
  validates :price, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01}
  validates :title, uniqueness: true
  validates :image_url, allow_blank: true, format: {
    with: %r{\. (gif|japg|png)\Z}i,
    message: 'must be a URL for GIF, JPG or PNG image.'
  }
end
```

Why have two test files? Wouldn't it cause confusion between two validations? I think I'm overthinking this and not understanding the whole testing concept but I can't seem to get a clear explanation regarding the YML file.

I'm fairly new to Rails so bear with me XD.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Nop, the fixture file contains representations of objects of that model. So you can use them in your testings without having to create manually new objects. Have a look: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html

Comment: @SergioAristizábal Oh wow, well that explains it. I was way off. I think I was confused partly because the YML file set objects default name as "one" and "two". I didn't know where it came from. Thanks for your explanation Sergio!